# dSYMs file is not generated

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I use XCode 7.3. I get export by

```
"Archive" > "Export" > "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" > Select Company > "Export one app for all compatible devices"
```

and I get `"Summary"` screen. In this screen, there is not check box about dSYM file. I click `"Next"` and I get ipa file. I upload this file to itunesconnect. In itunesconnect, when I go to `"iOS Builds"` and find my upload, I see `"Include Symbols" = YES`, but there is not a link for `"download dSYM file"`.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?  I am experiencing the same problem. Also, if I click the "Download dSYMs button for the Archive in XCodes Organizer window I get a message to say that "There are no dSYMs available for download".